# Remarkable2 SSH Batch Automation

Tags: ssh

So, I'm trying to automate deleting some files from my remarkable2 tablet via SSH, which is the only current way.

I usually run the following commands:

```
ssh root@[myip]
```

Once inside, I run:

```
rm /usr/share/remarkable/templates/[filename]
```

I don't have any problems with that, but when I try to automate it because of the number of lines I have to copy and paste (similar to scp code) it just won't run after it starts the connection.

For example, I can run this one directly to copy a file from my computer to the tablet

```
scp root@[myip]:/usr/share/remarkable/templates/[filename] "[Path where file is]"
```

My intent is a similar line of code to delete the file directly. I've tried

```
rm root@[myip]:/usr/share/remarkable/templates/[filename]
```

and other variants without much success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Was `ssh root@[ip] rm /usr/share/remarkable/templates/[filename]` one of the variants that you tried?

Comment: I hadn't tried it until now, and it worked! Thank you @SomethingDark